# Xamarin Android not respond after build with embedded jar

Tags: c#, xamarin, jar, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin android app and a binding library which contains a JAR file (build action as embedded jar).

The app build successful after I add the binding library as reference. However when I call the function in the jar, the app shows no respond (black screen). It doesn't throw any exception.

I try to debug in visual studio but when the line goes to the jar file (reach the line of the function in jar), it just disappear and I cannot find which line in the jar file goes wrong.

How can I debug in this situation?

Below is the code example, the BankCard is a class in the JAR file. 
The app does not respond after running `mBankCard.CardReaderDetact` function.

```
private BankCard mBankCard = new BankCard(Android.App.Application.Context);
byte[] respdata = new byte[100];
int[] resplen = new int[10];

public string cardreader()
{
    try
    {
        var retvalue = mBankCard.CardReaderDetact(BankCard.CardTypeNormal, BankCard.CardNmodePicc, BankCard.CardReadPiccdetact, respdata, resplen, "app1");
        return retvalue.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return "something wrong";
    }
}
```

**Updates**

I figure out that the problem is the line below. After it runs, it won't go back to the `MainActivity`.

```
JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle, class_ref, id_ctor_Landroid_content_Context_, __args);
```

Comment: What should `CardReaderDetact` do? Just return a value, or will it show some UI or anything like that? Does that method work in a Java Android App?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The CardReaderDetact just return a value. I've tried it in a Java Android App and it does work.